# Freeing static object memory completely

Tags: c++

Going through *Modern C++ Design* book, I came across this when the author talks about Singletons.

> C++ guarantees that static objects memory lasts for the duration of the program

(He uses this to ensure its always possible to recreate the "Phoneix" Singleton)

Is it the case that I can delete the static object but can never release it's memory?
If so, creating large static objects would mean it's memory is lost forever (till life of program ends)

Comment: why would you declare it as static when you dont want it to be alive for the duration of the program?

Comment: The answer is basically no. You cannot delete a static object, you can only delete objects that have been created with `new`. And yes, as long as an object exists, it occupies memory.

Comment: You cannot delete the static object

Comment: You could use a static pointer instead. You can also call the destructor of the static object, but can't free it's memory.

Comment: You can have a `static` *pointer* to a dynamically allocated object. The *pointer* would have a life-time for the duration of the program, but the object it points to can be created and destroyed multiple times.

Comment: @churill calling destructor of static object would lead to UB

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I added a few details to the question. The author is using this to his advantage to implement a "Phoenix" Singleton. A very large Singleton class of this type would consume a large chunk of memory for the duration of program, which I am worried about. (assuming no way to release the memory)

Comment: Use a static `std::unique_ptr` to hold (and own) the phoenix object.

Comment: Don't worry about it. Most likely it's doing it's own dynamic allocations and deallocations, with a *miniscule* static footprint. Even if it isn't you may find a "large" static size that's still well within the capability of your computer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If so, creating large static objects would mean it's memory is lost forever (till life of program ends)

This sounds as if it was a downside of static objects. Not sure, but maybe you missed the point. Sometimes you need an object to be alive for the whole duration of the program. How do you ensure that? You make it a static object, because...

> C++ guarantees that static objects memory lasts for the duration of the program

If you don’t want the object to be alive for the whole duration of the program, then don’t make it static.

Comment: Extrapolating, I assume it means 'Yes' to my question. Maybe I have to shy away from the implementation of Singleton in the book. I have different phases in my program and during one of which I need a large Singleton object. If the memory is forever occupied for the remainder of the program, then it is as good as a leaked. I will look up other Singleton patterns that obviate the use of static. Thanks.

Comment: @User10482 I would rather suggest you to reconsider if you really need a singleton. A singleton that does not live for the duration of the program doesnt really sound like a singleton. Actually I encountered many singletons, but up to today not a single one that really required to be a singleton